# Improving efficiency for a looping, mathematical script

Tags: python, performance, math, memory

I have written a script in order to compute a score, as well as a frequency for a list of genetic profiles.

A genetic profile here consists of a combination of SNPs. Each SNP has two alleles. The input file for 3 SNPs is something like below:

```
    AA   CC   TT
    AT   CC   TT
    TT   CC   TT
    AA   CG   TT
    AT   CG   TT
    TT   CG   TT
    AA   GG   TT
    AT   GG   TT
    TT   GG   TT
    AA   CC   TA
    AT   CC   TA
    TT   CC   TA
    AA   CG   TA
    AT   CG   TA
    TT   CG   TA
    AA   GG   TA
    AT   GG   TA
    TT   GG   TA
    AA   CC   AA
    AT   CC   AA
    TT   CC   AA
    AA   CG   AA
    AT   CG   AA
    TT   CG   AA
    AA   GG   AA
    AT   GG   AA
    TT   GG   AA
```

I then have the following code, which can take in the input file above and a table containing weights and frequencies, such as below:

```
(SNP        RiskAll  RefAll         OR            log(OR)    RiskAllFreq) # example header, not in file
SNP1             A       T       1.25    0.223143551314     0.97273 
SNP2             C       G       1.07    0.0676586484738    0.3     
SNP3             T       A       1.08    0.0769610411361    0.1136
```

It then computes a score, based on the sum of log odds ratios for each risk allele for each SNP in a genetic profile, as well as a frequency based on multiplying the allele frequencies, assuming Hardy Weinberg equilibrium.

```
import sys

snp={}
riskall={}
weights={}
freqs={}    # effect allele, *MAY NOT BE MINOR ALLELE

pop = int(int(sys.argv[4]) + 4) # for additional columns due to additional populations. the example table given only has one population (column 6)

# read in OR table
pos = 0
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        snp[pos]=(line.split()[0])
        riskall[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[1]
        weights[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[4]
        freqs[line.split()[0]]=line.split()[pop]

        pos+=1



### compute scores for each combination
with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        score=0
        freq=1
        for j in range(len(line.split())):
            rsid=snp[j]
            riskallele=riskall[rsid]
            frequency=freqs[rsid]
            wei=weights[rsid]
            allele1=line.split()[j][0]
            allele2=line.split()[j][1]
            if allele2 != riskallele:      # homozygous for ref
                score+=0
                freq*=(1-float(frequency))*(1-float(frequency))
            elif allele1 != riskallele and allele2 == riskallele:  # heterozygous, be sure that A2 is risk allele!
                score+=float(wei)
                freq*=2*(1-float(frequency))*(float(frequency))
            elif allele1 == riskallele: # and allele2 == riskall[snp[j]]:      # homozygous for risk, be sure to limit risk to second allele!
                score+=2*float(wei)
                freq*=float(frequency)*float(frequency)

            if freq < float(sys.argv[3]):   # threshold to stop loop in interest of efficiency 
                break

        print(','.join(line.split()) + "\t" + str(score) + "\t" + str(freq))
```

So far, I have set a variable where I can specify a threshold to break the loop when the frequency gets extremely low, for instance, at approximately 1e-10. I am looking to ramp this up to include at least 20 SNPs. What improvements can be done to speed up the script?

EDIT: Added example of table file.

EDIT 2: I have now tried running the script with a frequency threshold of 1e-4. It's been about six days so far and it's still running and that's too slow, so I'm looking for more suggestions!

EDIT 3 : Clarified input files, the headers are not actually in the input file, they are just an indication.

EDIT 4: Tried using Pandas, but it was slow, and not sure if vectorization is possible for this purpose. Dask has issues being installed on my Unix server. I have now changed all data structures to dictionaries as far as possible. What else can I do?

Comment: Use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Its a library for data manipulation and pandas operations would speedup your script.

Comment: Can you give the ``table`` file as well

Comment: @DeepakSaini Sure, I've added an example into my post.