# How can I utilize vectorization on my Pandas script for efficiency?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization

this is a continuation from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827565/improving-efficiency-for-a-looping-mathematical-script), where I wanted a faster and more efficient alternative to a standard Python loop, which performs some summing and multiplication on elements of each row.

Basically, what I have are two file inputs. One is a list of all combinations for a group of SNPs, for example below for 3 SNPs:

```
    AA   CC   TT
    AT   CC   TT
    TT   CC   TT
    AA   CG   TT
    AT   CG   TT
    TT   CG   TT
    AA   GG   TT
    AT   GG   TT
    TT   GG   TT
    AA   CC   TA
    AT   CC   TA
    TT   CC   TA
    AA   CG   TA
    AT   CG   TA
    TT   CG   TA
    AA   GG   TA
    AT   GG   TA
    TT   GG   TA
    AA   CC   AA
    AT   CC   AA
    TT   CC   AA
    AA   CG   AA
    AT   CG   AA
    TT   CG   AA
    AA   GG   AA
    AT   GG   AA
    TT   GG   AA
```

And the second is a table, containing some information for each SNP, notably their log(OR) for a disease and the frequency of the risk allele:

```
SNP1             A       T       1.25    0.223143551314     0.97273 
SNP2             C       G       1.07    0.0676586484738    0.3     
SNP3             T       A       1.08    0.0769610411361    0.1136
```

Below is my main code, in which I am looking to calculate a 'score' and a 'frequency' for each 'profile. The score is the sum of log(ORs) for each risk allele present in the profile, while the frequency is the frequencies multiplied together, assuming Hardy Weinberg equilibrium:

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = pd.read_csv(table2, sep="\t", header=None)

combinations = pd.read_csv(table1, sep=" ", header=None)

def score_freq(line):
    score=0
    freq=1
    for j in range(len(line)):
        if line[j][1] != numbers.values[j][1]:   # homozygous for ref
            score+=0
            freq*=(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][6]))*float(1-float(numbers.values[j][6])))
        elif line[j][0] != numbers.values[j][1] and line[j][1] == numbers.values[j][1]: # heterozygous
            score+=(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(2*(float(1-float(numbers.values[j][6]))*float(numbers.values[j][6])))
        elif line[j][0] == numbers.values[j][1]:   # homozygous for risk
            score+=2*(float(numbers.values[j][5]))
            freq*=(float(numbers.values[j][6])*float(numbers.values[j][6]))

        if freq < 1e-05:   # threshold to stop loop in interest of efficiency 
            break

    return pd.Series([score, freq])

combinations[['score', 'freq']] = combinations.apply(lambda row: score_freq(row), axis=1)
#combinations[['score', 'freq']] = score_freq(combinations.values) # vectorization?

print(combinations)
```

I was referring to [this site](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6), where they go over the fastest way to loop over a Pandas dataframe. I have been able to use the Pandas apply method, but I am not sure how to perform the vectorization method over the Pandas series. Other than that, do suggest any way in which I can improve my script to make it more efficient, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilising the NumPy Python library to make your pd script more efficient. The idea behind NumPy is that you can use vectorization to avoid FOR loops and therefore process loads of data very efficiently. When working with Numpy, you are basically converting your data into Numpy arrays. You can find the extensive documentation [here](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#numpy-arrays). To answer your question, you can perform mathematical operations on numpy arrays like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
a + 1                // to add 1 to every element in the array

a * 2                // to multiply each element in the array by 2
```

which is way more efficient than if you where to use FOR loops in pure python.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. How should I go about specifying a different math operation for each element in the array? For example, I have an AA, and a AT in the array, and the values for A is 0.1 while T is 0.9. Do I simply iterate over the array and do a check, or is there a better way?